# How can I use a formula to show given results instead of using if, else?

Tags: c, if-statement, formula

I have a homework prompt that is asking me to have these results given:

```
Enter the three values to test (a b c): 3 4 5
a < b < c Status: 1
Pythagorean Triplet Status: 1

Enter the three values to test (a b c): 3 5 6
a < b < c Status: 1
Pythagorean Triplet Status: 0

Enter the three values to test (a b c): 4 3 5
a < b < c Status: 0
Pythagorean Triplet Status: 0
```

This is what i have so far and i just feel lost:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define Status 1

int main()

{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int status;


  printf("Enter the three values to test (a b c):\n");
  scanf("%d%d%d\n", &a, &b, &c);
  printf("%d a < b < c Status: ",status);

  status =((((b-a)/2)+((b-a)/2))-((c-b)/2)+((c-b)/2))/2;

return(0);
}
```

I cannot use an if, else statement.  It needs to work for any three values that are plugged in.  I cannot figure out the correct formula to use to get this to work. Any suggestions on the formula?

Comment: Maybe you could give it your best shot and we help if it doesn't work

Comment: Homework and no attempt to solve it? -1. Show us your code, you have done so far and where you have problems with.

Comment: I know the formula is off, I've been trying to find abstract ways of getting it to work for a couple hours

Comment: yes, i have that at the top of my code but I forgot to add stdio.h

Answer (score 0):

Something like a * a + b * b == c * c ?

Comment: @mbratch no, `==` yields an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
status = !(a*a + b*b -c*c);
```